# What if strings overlap in the memory?

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory

Say, we are doing the following:

```
char* pc1;
char* pc2;
```

And then we can do

```
pc1 = "STRING";
pc2 = "ANOTHERSTRING";
```

My question is, what if `pc1` is just 2 bytes before the `pc2` in the memory and they collide? Why are we able to set a string literal to pointers and with infinite length when we can't know that they don't collide/overlap?

Edit: What I intended to ask was only if `pc1` was say, 16 bytes before the `pc2` in the memory meanwhile pointing to a 300 bytes long string. But pointers actually point to strings that are somewhere else in the memory so my question is clear right now, thanks to everyone. I didn't choose `pc1` to be a suffix of `pc2` on purpose, however, that looks like another story.

Comment: if they collide it means that the compiler is seriously buggy.

Comment: The *strings* are allocated a place in memory, then that pointer value is assigned to your `char *` variables. The variables themselves don't "contain" the strings, and there is no possibility of overlap.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No it doesn't. String literals are allowed to share memory if one is a suffix of the other.

Comment: What is the problem if pc1 points into the middle of pc2? How do you want to implement a search function or a function like strtok when no second pointer is allowed to point into a string (which in C is just an array, so the same questions would arise for arrays and not only strings)? Or maybe even more basic: are you talking about any strings or only string literals?

Comment: Oh, I didn't intend to ask what if one is the suffix of another and I understand until this point but this is also interesting because if we change one, it effects both.

Comment: but you _cannot_ change string literals. It's undefined behaviour. And not recommended to do `char *xx="foo"` without `const`

Comment: It isn't clear what unsesirable scenario you have in mind. Can you show some code that in your opinion would be problematic if the strings were merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be confused about what the assignments to `pc1` and `pc2` are doing. Those statements are *not* copying the contents of the referenced string to the memory location pointed to by `pc1` and `pc2`. They are *changing* the memory location that `pc1` and `pc2` are pointing to. To see what I mean let's add a little more to your code and make it a complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char* pc1 = NULL;
    char* pc2 = NULL;

    printf("pc1 pointing to location in memory: %p\n", pc1);
    printf("pc2 pointing to location in memory: %p\n", pc2);

    pc1 = "STRING";
    pc2 = "ANOTHERSTRING";

    printf("pc1 pointing to location in memory: %p\n", pc1);
    printf("pc2 pointing to location in memory: %p\n", pc2);
}
```

Now compile and run this. When I do so on my machine I get the following output:

```
pc1 pointing to location in memory: (nil)
pc2 pointing to location in memory: (nil)
pc1 pointing to location in memory: 0x5578b61a57b8
pc2 pointing to location in memory: 0x5578b61a57bf
```

`pc1` and `pc2` start by pointing to "nothing" (`NULL` or `nil`). Then after the assignment statements we have pointed them to different locations in memory that contain the strings "STRING" and "ANOTHERSTRING", respectively.

Answer (score 0):

`pc1` and `pc2` are pointers. The memory layout can be something like this:

```
Address     Contents
1000        ANOTHERSTRING\0
1020        1007        pc1 variable
1024        1000        pc2 variable
```

This shows that the contents of the strings can overlap, but the pointers are still distinct.

The reason this is allowed is because you're not allowed to modify string literals. So you don't have to worry about changing the contents of the string that `pc1` points to and that affecting the value of `pc2`, or vice versa.

Note this can only happen when you use pointers to string literals. There's no overlap if you do:

```
char pc1[] = "STRING";
char pc2[] = "ANOTHERSTRING";
```

Each of these is a distinct array, and the literals are merely their initial values.